# http gets html before page finished loading

Tags: java, android, http, screen-scraping

I am trying to get some info of [that page here](http://forecast.io/#/f/51.7589,-0.2343/1370905200)

but what happens, there is a 1 sec. loading on the page so my http get all the info of the loading page not the the one after the loading..altough the page doesn't redirect in between loading and viewing info.

so basically the http responce come with html of the loading.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you gve more info please

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a **web browser** that supports Javascript and can be **embedded** into your Java application.

This is not easy with few documentation. :(

[**JxBrowser**](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) seems to be one of the simplest solution but AFAIK it's not free but you could try asking them if your project is open-source...

Comment: im not using a webBroswer i am using a http client that loads the page then i get the info by buffer reader

Comment: And that's precisely the issue: you can't simply use an HTTP client that is **unable to interpret dynamic content like Javascript**. You need something more powerful: a **web browser**.

Answer (score 1):

The site is using an AJAX request as the page loads to get the actual data.  The AJAX request corresponding to the URL you refer to is:

http://forecast.io/forecast?q=51.7589,-0.2343,1370905200&satellites

You'll notice it yields a JSON response containing the forecast data.

I discovered this using [screen-scraper's](http://screen-scraper.com/) proxy, though you could also use something like Charles or HttpFox to determine it.  The key is to proxy the site and determine which AJAX request corresponds to the information you're after.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a web page on a browser, it returns html. The html is just text. Your browser reads it and renders it into the view you are looking at right now. This is static content. Within the html, you can embed scripts, ex. javascript, which your browser can run to send more HTTP requests and dynamically modify this view.

Since you are sending your HTTP requests with come HTTP client that is not a browser (and that cannot execute javascript), all you get is the bytes from the HTTP response, probably just html. If you want the information that is loaded in the browser, you will have to figure out the which requests retrieve it and how to parse their responses.